biblatex does not work in TexStudio
I have this beamer presentation in overleaf:
ejemplo.tex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliografia.bib}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}   
        My cite.\cite{testbib}
    \end{frame}
    
    \begin{frame}{References}       
        % This prints the bibliography on the slide
        \printbibliography
    \end{frame}
    
\end{document}

and the bibliografia.bib:
@online{testbib,
    author = "someone",
    year={2030},
    title = "Some title",
    url  = "www.someurl.com"
}

It works ok:

Now, I want to work locally in TexStudio, I put both files in the same directory, but it seems the bib file is not read:

Any idea?

texstudio is just the editor you use to write the file. latex never reads the .bib file,  you need to run pdflatex, then biber then pdflatex twice more.

overleaf uses latexmk to decide if it needs to run biber or pdflatex again, so an alternative is to use latexmk locally rather then pdflatex, it will run pdflatex and biber as many times as needed to resolve all references.

Did you reconfigure your editor to use biber instead of bibtex? I do think texstudio has a configuration option where one chooses between biber (biblatex) style or bibtex style.

Does this answer your question? Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations or Question mark or bold citation key instead of citation number

Yes it works. Thanks cabohah!
